# Inkscape gradient-stop distribution

Tags: inkscape, gradient, distribute

Is there any way to auto-align gradient stops along the length of a gradient in the same manner that objects can be distributed with relation to the page?

Comment: Nothing automatic far as I know. However you could align the stops of a gradient using snapping to paths which have been distributed using Align and Distribute. [See example here](https://imgur.com/rYFkzjm). I can add this as an answer if it's any good for you.

Comment: @billy Kerr This is the workaround I'd come up with – bit of a fuss, but better than manual adjustment. As 'No' is a valid answer, feel free to push the button. Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing automatic as far as I know. Perhaps an extension could be written for it.

Anyway, you could align the stops of a gradient using snapping to paths which have been distributed using Align & Distribute.

For example

[image]

Comment: Maybe this should be a bug report.  https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues

Comment: @chicks A missing feature is not "a bug".

Comment: gitlab/github issues are also often used for feature requests.  Inkscape seems to follow that trend.  https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&label_name[]=improvement